# CSS Browser's text selection highlight color

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, cross-browser

Is it possible to get the browser's default (or themed, assuming there are browser themes? I've never looked) text selection color?

#### Background

I'm trying to make an `<input type="date" />` act like it has a `placeholder` attribute, like the HTML5 `<input type="text" />` does.  In case it matters, I'm using Bootstrap.

So far, I've got

*CSS*

```
/* allow date inputs to have placeholders */
/* display placeholder text */
input[type="date"].emptyDate:before {
    content: attr(placeholder);
    color: #999;
}

/* hide default mm/dd/yyyy text when empty value and not in focus */
input[type=date].emptyDate:not(:focus) {
    color: transparent;
}

/* hide default mm/dd/yyyy text when empty value, not in focus, and
   selected (ctrl + a) */
input[type="date"].emptyDate::selection:not(:focus) {
    color: transparent;
    background-color: lightblue;
}

/* hide placeholder text when empty value, but in focus */
input[type="date"].emptyDate:focus:before {
    content: "";
}
```

*Javascript*

```
function setEmptyDateInputClass(input) {
    if ($(input).val()) {
        $(input).removeClass("emptyDate");
    } else {
        $(input).addClass("emptyDate");
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $.each($("input[type=date]"), function (i, input) {
        // set initial class
        setEmptyDateInputClass(input);

        // set class on value change
        $(input).change(function () { setEmptyDateInputClass(this);});
    });
});
```

#### Issues

I'm having two issues.  The first, and the one I'm asking in this question (I'll post another question if everyone obeys the rules and no one posts answers to multiple questions) is, is there a way to get the browser's default (or themed) selection background color so that, either with CSS or manually with Javascript, the `lightblue` isn't static?  (Also, light blue isn't the right color, but that's just a matter of a screenshot and mspaint.)

```
input[type="date"].emptyDate::selection:not(:focus) {
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

My second, bonus issue is, I'm having issues selecting `:before::selection` in order to set the background color of selected ::before content.

```
/* always active when .emptyDate */
input[type="date"].emptyDate::selection:before {
    background-color: lightblue;
}

/* never active */
input[type="date"].emptyDate:before::selection {
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use specificity on `::selection` like so:

CSS

```
.red::selection {
   background-color: red;
   color: #fff;
   }

.green::selection{
   background-color:green;
   color:#fff;
   }
```

HTML

```
<span class="red">I am highlighted in red, </span>
<span class="green">and I am highlighted in green,</span>
<span class="">and I am highlighted as per browser default.</span>
```

Example: http://www.bootply.com/KEEvWSlP0F

Comment: How would I go about applying a class to `attr(placeholder)`?  The `content` rule doesn't allow html.